# Wordpress login throwing error 606 blocked

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to login using URL http://www.abcd.com/blog/wp-login.php.
after entering credentials and submitting form i am getting error 606 blocked.

Complete error message is as below:

**Error 606 blocked.
blocked
Guru Meditation:
XID: 477926299
varnish cache server**

What wrong going on??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of search and study, randomly i found a solution.
Rather than using **http://www.abcd.com/blog/wp-login.php**, i am using **http://www.abcd.com/blog/admin** for login and its working for me.

Using **http://www.abcd.com/blog/admin** redirects me to **http://www.abcd.com/blog/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.abcd.com%2Fblog%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1** and then i am using my credentials and its working. Thanks